# Can I use the Angel of Grace exile ability when I have negative life?

Tags: magic-the-gathering-arena

[Angel of Grace](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=457145)'s last ability reads: "4WW, Exile Angel of Grace from your graveyard: Your life total becomes 10."

Is it possible to use this ability after being dealt lethal damage? Does the game allow me to exile the angel while I have a negative life total, or does the game end immediately?

Comment: Do you have some effect preventing you from losing the game at negative life, or are you asking in general?

Comment: I might ask this over on https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/ since they probably know if it is legal in the card game and then it comes down to weather the game is programmed correctly.

Comment: If you do ask over there, they like you to tag the game, so it's clear you're not asking a general rules Q.

Comment: I was asking in general, since I didn't know that losing was a state-based action; I tried to do it once but I couldn't manage to do it so I was wondering if it was a matter of enabling  Full Control or it was forbidden by the rules

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Short answer:

No, you cannot activate the ability after lethal damage has been dealt. You can, however, activate the ability before the damage has been dealt.

Long answer:

In a normal situation, you would lose the game as soon your life total is 0 or less. Losing the game is a state-based action, so no-one receives priority before losing. The game ends immediately (presuming two player game).

However there are cards that prevent you from losing the game while having 0 or less life. In this case, activating the ability of Angel of Grace will cause you to gain life so that your life total becomes 10, even after "lethal" damage has been dealt.